# Zeppelin - output format

Tags: hive, bigdata, hql, apache-zeppelin

I have a problem with Zeppelin. Zeppelin have given me an output salary with comma. It is any possible way to print the result without the comma?[my outpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1pqc.png) I am using distribution Hortonworks 2.4.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using zeppelin 0.5.x or 0.6.x

In the latest version, you can change the number display format.